# Facebook conversions API : No event in events manager

Tags: facebook, facebook-marketing-api

Since the last 2th september I have an issue with the Facebook Conversion API. The event sends fine to the event manager when using the 'test_event_code'.  However, when I remove that test_event_code attribute, ie to make this same event in prod. I'am not receiving the events in event manager...

Sending :

```
{"data":
[{
"event_name":"ViewContent",
"event_time":1663069325,
"user_data":{
"client_ip_address":"146.185.154.173",
"client_user_agent":"Mozilla\/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit\/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome\/104.0.0.0 Safari\/537.36",
"external_id":"2125",
"fbp":null,
"fbc":null},
"action_source":"website",
"event_source_url":"https:\/\/brulafine.com"
}]
}
```

Answer receive :

```
{"events_received":1,"messages":[],"fbtrace_id":"ASyUd4Q50ERaB347QgPwPU7"}
```

client ip adress and user_agent are real not dummy.

Before the 2th sept it works :(
Do you know if the api has evolved or if any changes are required since that date ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

I am also encountering the same problem, which I have posted in their developer community https://developers.facebook.com/support/bugs/3318916751722481/?join_id=fc8d321bc982f4

Let's see what solutions they can provide.

PS I was gonna add this in the comment section but it requires 50 reputations in order to do it, which I don't have